# What iOS supports tel:// file handling?

Tags: iphone, ios

What was the earliest iOS which supported the `tel://` file handler to launch the phone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tel has been supported since iOS 1.0. At least in Safari. There was no public SDK yet.

Comment: Since 2.0 because that was the first public SDK.

Comment: Just aside, but why do you want to know this?

Comment: I have an app based on these file handlers and I wanted to know the earliest iOS that I can support. It's a speed dial app for an EMT service. I actually forgot to change it before uploading and I'm waiting for review on an update.  Check out my app: http://iTunes.com/apps/hatzalah Thanks.